# PHP url # split

Tags: .htaccess, parsing, url

I have a .htaccess file with those contents:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ([^/\.]+)$ index.php?string=$1&match=all [L]
```

So when I type: domain.com/test
the page redirects to *domain.com/index.php?string=test&match=all*

But if I want to reach this page: domain.com/test#sub1

the page redirects to *domain.com/index.php?string=**test**&match=all*

instead of *domain.com/index.php?string=**test#sub1**&match=all*

How do I proceed?

Comment: Hashes aren't sent to the server so it sees `domain.com/test` not `domain.com/test#sub1`

Comment: The `#` is only used by the browser, and not sent with the HTTP request. The server never sees it.

Comment: Indeed, you were just a bit faster :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchors/hashes are only used by the browser. The server won't see requests for those, because such a request would be invalid. (There is no "test#sub1" file, only a "test" file.) It has no way of knowing you're just wanting to access an anchor and not trying to access a file that doesn't exist, so such information is not passed to the web server.

EDIT: Also, redirecting *everything* through a single php file just seems like malpractice to me. Maybe there's something special going on here that makes it a reputable approach though.

Comment: That's the common 'front controller' pattern used by many PHP frameworks.

Comment: hmm.. good to know. it just seems odd to me, but then I haven't worked with too many frameworks lately.